# .htaccess error internal server 500

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with my .htaccess :

This code works :

```
    
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^classement-triathlon-d1-2016-([^/]*)$ /classement.php?genre=$1 [L]
```

But when I want add this line :

> RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /news.php?slug=$1 [L]

I have this error :
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, postmaster@mywebsite.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: "More information about this error may be available in the server error log." So have you checked the server error log?

Comment: I don't see on the logs my new url rewrite..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule is fine but you need to exclude the dot in the pattern so that it can not match the rewrite destination :

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ /news.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Comment: On the other side, my homepage don't works...
Do you have solution ?